# Getting error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php, html, database

I am getting an error which says,

> mysqli_result needs 1 parameter
>
> mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean

my full code, 
now i am trying to host this website online.

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'id627165_root';
$dbpass = 'veneeth';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: '. mysqli_error());
}
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","id627165_root","veneeth");

if(!$con)
{
    die("Can't connect".mysqli_error());
}

$AadharNumber=$_SESSION['AadharNumber'];
mysqli_select_db($con,"id627165_mydb");
$sql="select * from Aadardetails where AadharNumber=$AadharNumber";
$myData=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<div style='margin-left:580px; margin-top:-50px; position:absolute'><table border=1 cellpadding='9px' cellspacing='9px'>

<tr bgcolor=#00FFCC class=color>
<th>Fields</th>
<th>Data</th>
</tr>";

while($record=mysqli_fetch_array($myData))
{
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>UserName</td><td>".$record['Name']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>Gender</td><td>".$record['Gender']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>Age</td><td>".$record['Age']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>DateOfBirth</td><td>".$record['DOB']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>Address</td><td>".$record['Address']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>Email</td><td>".$record['Email']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>MobileNo</td><td><a style='color:#FFF' href='EditMobile.php?oldnum=".$record['MobileNo']."'>".$record['MobileNo']."</a>
    </td></tr>";
    $mobi=$record['MobileNo'];
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>State</td><td>".$record['State']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>PinCode</td><td>".$record['PINCode']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>AadharNumber</td><td>".$record['AadharNumber']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>EnRollMentNumber</td><td>".$record['EnrollmentNumber']."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table> </div>";

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
    {
        if(isset($_POST["Request"]))
        {
            $newnum=$mobi;
            $addar=$_SESSION['AadharNumber'];
            //echo date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
            $sql = "insert into ticketrequest(AadharNum,MobileNumber,Date,Status) values('$addar','$newnum','".date('Y-m-d')."','Pending')";
            mysqli_select_db('id627165_mydb');
            $retval1 = mysqli_query( $sql, $conn );
            if(!$retval1)
{
  die('Could not sent Request data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
print  '<script>alert("Request sent successfully")</script>';
        }
    }


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

till now i was using local host to run the website,now i am using 000webhost to host my website online.
so while trying to view this page its showing the error
can anyone resolve this problem

Comment: Is AadharNumber column type INTEGER or is VARCHAR ? If is VARCHAR AadharNumber=$AadharNumber must be AadharNumber='$AadharNumber'

Comment: @AlivetoDie i have used connection for 1 time

Comment: @MTK its bigint

Comment: Ok. So AadharNumber=$AadharNumber is correct

Comment: @gudisaveneeth  use this code from the link (don't look at the output,just take code):- https://eval.in/839425   .use it and let me know worked or not?

Comment: @AlivetoDie yaa code is now working,and thank you so much for helping me

Comment: @AlivetoDie Tell please why did you reopen the question? To answer it and get points?

Comment: @u_mulder  Because the link given for duplicate is not answering him completely.  He have multiple other issues like:- 1.`session not started`,2. `connection closed at wrong place`.3 `connection used wrongly`,4 `"wrong function usage for connection error problem"` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check comments for changes:-

```
<?php
session_start();//check change
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'id627165_root';
$dbpass = 'veneeth';

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","id627165_root","veneeth","id627165_mydb"); //check change

if(!$con)
{
    die("Can't connect".mysqli_connect_error()); //check change
}

$AadharNumber=$_SESSION['AadharNumber'];
$sql="select * from Aadardetails where AadharNumber=$AadharNumber";
$myData=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("query error:-".mysqli_error($con));

echo "<div style='margin-left:580px; margin-top:-50px; position:absolute'><table border=1 cellpadding='9px' cellspacing='9px'>

<tr bgcolor=#00FFCC class=color>
<th>Fields</th>
<th>Data</th>
</tr>";

// use _assoc
while($record=mysqli_fetch_assoc($myData)) 
{
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>UserName</td><td>".$record['Name']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>Gender</td><td>".$record['Gender']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>Age</td><td>".$record['Age']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>DateOfBirth</td><td>".$record['DOB']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>Address</td><td>".$record['Address']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>Email</td><td>".$record['Email']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>MobileNo</td><td><a style='color:#FFF' href='EditMobile.php?oldnum=".$record['MobileNo']."'>".$record['MobileNo']."</a>
    </td></tr>";
    $mobi=$record['MobileNo'];
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>State</td><td>".$record['State']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>PinCode</td><td>".$record['PINCode']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>AadharNumber</td><td>".$record['AadharNumber']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class=txtcolor><td>EnRollMentNumber</td><td>".$record['EnrollmentNumber']."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table> </div>";
mysqli_close($con); // close connection here
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
    {
        if(isset($_POST["Request"]))
        {
            $newnum=$mobi;
            $addar=$_SESSION['AadharNumber'];
            //check changes
            $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,"id627165_mydb");
            if(!$conn)
            {
              die('Could not connect: '. mysqli_connect_error());
            }
            $sql = "insert into ticketrequest(AadharNum,MobileNumber,Date,Status) values('$addar','$newnum','".date('Y-m-d')."','Pending')";
            $retval1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); //check change
            if(!$retval1){
                die('Could not sent Request data: ' . mysqli_error($conn)); //check change
            }
            print  '<script>alert("Request sent successfully")</script>';
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
?>
```

Note:- Please use `prepared statements` of `mysqli_*` for queries to prevent your code from ***`SQL Injection`***.It's important and necessary.